# why does javascript bitwise & on binary numbers increases length of binary string

Tags: javascript, binary, bitwise-operators

In the following code it is my understanding that & is supposed to give a resulting binary string with ones where each corresponding digit on each string are both 1's, however the result I got is: "98435",  what I expected was: "101011". Where is my misunderstanding? how can I achieve what I am attempting to do?

```
const bool = "101011";
const bool2 = "111011";
const and = bool & bool2;
console.log("bool: "+bool+", bool2: "+bool2+", &: "+and);
```

Comment: 101,001 & 111,011 (base 10) is, quite correctly, 98435 base 10 - look at that binary of those numbers to understand why ...

Comment: `(parseInt("101011",2) & parseInt("111011",2)).toString(2)` is what you *think* your code is doing - javascript doesn't work that way

Comment: (43 & 59).toString(2) - i think you need to do like this

Comment: "*Where is my misunderstanding?*". In thinking that "101011" is a number, it's a string. ;-)

Comment: Worth noting that the string is "coerced" to a **decimal** number when used in a mathematical operation (except `+`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript, like most languages, assumes humans use base 10 in code

Your code uses STRINGS though

When you use any mathematical operator (except `+`) Javascript tries to be nice, and make a Number out of the string - but, it's a BASE 10 number (unless the first digit in the string is a `0` and the rest of the digits are octal (0 to 7), in that case, the number is considered to be an BASE 8)

So the string 101011 is "coerced" to be the Number 101011 = `11000101010010011` and 111011 becomes 111011 = `11011000110100011`

```
11000101010010011 (binary) &  
11011000110100011 (binary)  
-----------------
11000000010000011 (binary) = 98435 (decimal)
```

However, easy to fix:

```js
const bool = "101011";
const bool2 = "111011";
const and = (parseInt(bool,2) & parseInt(bool2,2)).toString(2);
console.log("bool: "+bool+", bool2: "+bool2+", &: "+and);
```